# What is a command-line client for FastCGI?

Tags: fastcgi, command-line-tool

I'm looking for something like [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [httpie](https://httpie.org/), but instead of connecting to an Internet socket and speaking HTTP 1.1 it connects to a Unix socket and speaks FastCGI.

This is for debugging purposes. [ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/)/[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) do not quite cut it because of the nature of the protocol.

Comment: On ubuntu 20 I use the `cgi-fcgi` command, install it with `apt isntall libfcgi-bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the fast-cgi-client and it works fine.

https://github.com/hollodotme/fast-cgi-client

You can also try the pure fcgi-client

https://github.com/NiR-/fcgi-client

Comment: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/directly-connect-php-fpm/